# Civilians and nonmilitary personnel

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Imagine a country keeps attacking another country and kills all the people living in different parts of that land; I was wondering if you could let me know which one of the following self-made sentences sounds more natural to you:

> - As a human being, I condemn that country for its attacks on the civilians.
> - As a human being, I condemn that country for its attacks on the nonmilitary personnel.

Bringing up this question, although,I know "civilians" and "non-military personnel" are identical concepts, I need to find out of they are interchangeable in this sense or not.

Comment: Punctunation is important. Look closely at **although,I know** in your question.

Comment: This is not a condemnation of one specific attack on one specific group of civilians, so the definite article **the** is wrong in both sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personnel implies being employed, or engaged in some formal joint undertaking. I would not usually think of children as being included as personnel.

I think civilians better suits your intention.

Comment: Could you please answer an additional question? I need to know if it is possible to substitute the verbs "sentence" with "condemn" in above sentences?

Comment: @A-friend that would be better done in a different question. Questions are free (and more good questions give more reputation)!

Answer (score 2):

The sentence would flow better by removing "the" - when you say "its attacks on the civilians" it sounds like you're referring to a specific group of civilians whereas your condemnation actually extends from attacks on civilians in general. Try: As a human being, I condemn that country for its attacks on civilians.

Comment: Although I agree with you, this doesn't really answer the question.